# "UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found" when call function in C source code

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to call the function in C source code with JNI in Android , but it crash.

The Android project is like the following picture.

[image][image]

The code in the JAVA is like the following:

```
public static native void startRTSPserver();
    static {
        Log.i(TAG, "Load Libraries...");
        System.loadLibrary("live555");
    }
```

The Android crash when I call function **`startRTSPserver();`** at **`(SoftAP.java:302)`**

The code of **`live555MediaServer.cpp`** in C source code is like the following:

```
#include <BasicUsageEnvironment.hh>
#include "DynamicRTSPServer.hh"
#include "version.hh"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_softap_SoftAP_startRTSPserver(JNIEnv *env , jobject thiz){
//int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNIMsg", "RTSP Start---live555MediaServer");
        // Begin by setting up our usage environment:
          TaskScheduler* scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();
          UsageEnvironment* env = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*scheduler);

          UserAuthenticationDatabase* authDB = NULL;
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
}
```

The error log is like the following:

```
W/dalvikvm(13181): No implementation found for native Lcom/softap/SoftAP;.startRTSPserver:()V
D/AndroidRuntime(13181): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(13181): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40db2450)
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
E/AndroidRuntime(13181): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13181): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.softap.SoftAP.startRTSPserver:()V
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at com.softap.SoftAP.startRTSPserver(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at com.softap.SoftAP$6.onClick(SoftAP.java:302)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(13181):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

------------------------------------EDIT----------------------------------

The code of Android.mk is like the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)


LOCAL_MODULE := live555

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := \
    -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DNO_SSTREAM -DBSD=1 -DNO_SSTREAM -fexceptions -DANDROID -DXLOCALE_NOT_USED  

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH) \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/BasicUsageEnvironment/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/BasicUsageEnvironment \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/UsageEnvironment/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/UsageEnvironment \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/groupsock/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/groupsock \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/liveMedia/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/liveMedia \

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    live555.cpp \
    mediaServer/live555MediaServer.cpp \
    mediaServer/DynamicRTSPServer.cpp \
    liveMedia/Media.cpp \
    liveMedia/MediaSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/FramedSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/FramedFileSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/FramedFilter.cpp \
    liveMedia/ByteStreamFileSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/ByteStreamMultiFileSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/ByteStreamMemoryBufferSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/BasicUDPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/DeviceSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/AudioInputDevice.cpp \
    liveMedia/WAVAudioFileSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2Demux.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2DemuxedElementaryStream.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEGVideoStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2VideoStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2VideoStreamDiscreteFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4VideoStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4VideoStreamDiscreteFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/H264VideoStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/H264VideoStreamDiscreteFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEGVideoStreamParser.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2AudioStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2AudioRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4LATMAudioRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4ESVideoRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4GenericRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3FileSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3Transcoder.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3ADU.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3ADUdescriptor.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3ADUinterleaving.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3ADUTranscoder.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3StreamState.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3Internals.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3InternalsHuffman.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3InternalsHuffmanTable.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3ADURTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2VideoRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2TransportStreamMultiplexor.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2TransportStreamFromPESSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2TransportStreamFromESSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2TransportStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/ADTSAudioFileSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/H263plusVideoRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/H263plusVideoStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/H263plusVideoStreamParser.cpp \
    liveMedia/AC3AudioStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/AC3AudioRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/DVVideoStreamFramer.cpp \
    liveMedia/DVVideoRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/JPEGVideoSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/AMRAudioSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/AMRAudioFileSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/InputFile.cpp \
    liveMedia/StreamReplicator.cpp \
    liveMedia/MediaSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/FileSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/BasicUDPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/AMRAudioFileSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/H264VideoFileSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2AudioRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3ADURTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2VideoRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4LATMAudioRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4GenericRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4ESVideoRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/H263plusVideoRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/H264VideoRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/DVVideoRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/AC3AudioRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/VorbisAudioRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/VP8VideoRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/GSMAudioRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/JPEGVideoRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/SimpleRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/AMRAudioRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/T140TextRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/TCPStreamSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/OutputFile.cpp \
    liveMedia/uLawAudioFilter.cpp \
    liveMedia/RTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/MultiFramedRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/SimpleRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/H261VideoRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/H264VideoRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/QCELPAudioRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/AMRAudioRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/JPEGVideoRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/VorbisAudioRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/VP8VideoRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/RTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/MultiFramedRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/AudioRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/VideoRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/TextRTPSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/RTPInterface.cpp \
    liveMedia/RTCP.cpp \
    liveMedia/rtcp_from_spec.c \
    liveMedia/RTSPServer.cpp \
    liveMedia/RTSPClient.cpp \
    liveMedia/RTSPCommon.cpp \
    liveMedia/RTSPServerSupportingHTTPStreaming.cpp \
    liveMedia/SIPClient.cpp \
    liveMedia/MediaSession.cpp \
    liveMedia/ServerMediaSession.cpp \
    liveMedia/PassiveServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/OnDemandServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/FileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG4VideoFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/H264VideoFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/H263plusVideoFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/WAVAudioFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/AMRAudioFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3AudioFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2VideoFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2FileServerDemux.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG1or2DemuxedServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2TransportFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/ADTSAudioFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/DVVideoFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/AC3AudioFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2TransportUDPServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/ProxyServerMediaSession.cpp \
    liveMedia/QuickTimeFileSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/QuickTimeGenericRTPSource.cpp \
    liveMedia/AVIFileSink.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2IndexFromTransportStream.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2TransportStreamIndexFile.cpp \
    liveMedia/MPEG2TransportStreamTrickModeFilter.cpp \
    liveMedia/MatroskaFile.cpp \
    liveMedia/MatroskaFileParser.cpp \
    liveMedia/EBMLNumber.cpp \
    liveMedia/MatroskaDemuxedTrack.cpp \
    liveMedia/MatroskaFileServerDemux.cpp \
    liveMedia/H264VideoMatroskaFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/VP8VideoMatroskaFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/AACAudioMatroskaFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/AC3AudioMatroskaFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/MP3AudioMatroskaFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/VorbisAudioMatroskaFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/T140TextMatroskaFileServerMediaSubsession.cpp \
    liveMedia/DarwinInjector.cpp \
    liveMedia/BitVector.cpp \
    liveMedia/StreamParser.cpp \
    liveMedia/DigestAuthentication.cpp \
    liveMedia/our_md5.c \
    liveMedia/our_md5hl.c \
    liveMedia/Base64.cpp \
    liveMedia/Locale.cpp \
    groupsock/GroupsockHelper.cpp \
    groupsock/GroupEId.cpp \
    groupsock/inet.c \
    groupsock/Groupsock.cpp \
    groupsock/NetInterface.cpp \
    groupsock/NetAddress.cpp \
    groupsock/IOHandlers.cpp \
    UsageEnvironment/UsageEnvironment.cpp \
    UsageEnvironment/HashTable.cpp \
    UsageEnvironment/strDup.cpp \
    BasicUsageEnvironment/BasicUsageEnvironment0.cpp \
    BasicUsageEnvironment/BasicUsageEnvironment.cpp \
    BasicUsageEnvironment/BasicTaskScheduler0.cpp \
    BasicUsageEnvironment/BasicTaskScheduler.cpp \
    BasicUsageEnvironment/DelayQueue.cpp \
    BasicUsageEnvironment/BasicHashTable.cpp \

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Does somebody know why it crash ? Did I missing something ?

Comment: can you show Android.mk?

Comment: @Jayesh I have add the Android.mk

Comment: So your `DynamicRTSPServer.cpp` server file contain definition for `startRTSPserver` right?

Comment: I think in `cpp` file you should write `extern "C"` before `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_softap_SoftAP_startRTSPserver`.

Comment: `startRTSPserver` will call `DynamicRTSPServer.cpp`

Comment: @Jayesh I have try to add `extern "C"` , but it is the same.

Comment: Try adding the library to both `<name>.apk/lib/armeabi/` and `<name>.apk/lib/armeabi-v7a/` to ensure the library is being loaded. Did you use `javah` to generate `Lcom/softap/SoftAP;.startRTSPserver:()V`? Also, see the FAQ on `UnsatisfiedLinkError` at Android's [JNI Native Libraries](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries)

Comment: @noloader There has library in `/libs/armeabi` .No , I didn't use `javah` to generate Lcom/softap/SoftAP;.startRTSPserver:()V...

Comment: @noloader Which C file should I generate header file by using `javah` ?

Comment: No, you don't need `javah` to run your project. And the signature of the `startRTSPserver()` native method looks good. You do need `extern "C"`. Make sure this change happens in file `mediaServer/live555MediaServer.cpp`.

Comment: Is it normal that the java method is declared `static`? The C code has an extra `jobject` parameter...

Comment: @Martin So you make changes in `mediaServe/live555MediaServer.cpp` for `extern "C"` but still same error, right? Ok , run  `nm -gC liblive555.so` command and look is `startRTSPserver` symbol there?

Comment: @Jayesh I run the command , and it show like the following:
`C:\Users\Wun\workspace\SoftAP\libs\armeabi>nm -gC liblive555.so`

`nm: liblive555.so: no symbols`

Comment: @Martin might be that's problem , because linking is successfully done, but, on runtime, your program crashes, because of "symbols not found" error.  So it's look your `.so` is broken somehow.

Comment: @Jayesh what it mean for **no symbols**?

Comment: @Jayesh I have try to use **`nm -gC`** for Android NDK-Sample(**`Hello-jni`** and `hello-gl2`) , it also show the **`no symbols`**...

Comment: @Martin `no symbol` means symbol less. It is alm wrong for an archive library a symbol table. Perhaps some{one,thing} strip(1)ed it by mistake?Looks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923896/ndk-profiling-showing-so-has-no-symbols